# How to set multiple CODEOWNERS in a repository in Github

Tags: github

I want to find a solution to set multiple CODEOWNERS file in a repository.
I know,  in CODEOWNERS documentation it allows only one CODEOWNERS in one reposiotry. but I have also read using GITHUB Action you can defined multiple CODEOWNERS File, but exact example I have not found.

If you have any solution, please leave a link in the comment.

Comment: Where did you see it in github action?  Would love to learn more.

Answer (score 6):

You can define as many codeowners as you want inside "CODEOWNERS" file.
For whole repo:

```
* @username1 @username2
```

For separate file inside repo:

```
/src/somefolder/somefile.txt @username3 @username4
```

Comment: The question is about multiple codeowners files, not multiple owner specs.